# C# Azure CosmosDb and Mongo - how to know if Find is hitting an index, and which are the best indexing recommendations for this scenario?

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 API that saves documents in Azure CosmosDb using Mongo Driver nuget package v2.11.

First of all, my document's class:

```
public class Customer
{
   public Guid CustomerId {get;set;}

   public string Email {get;set;}

   public int Channel {get;set;}

   public string PartitionKey
   {
       get { return GetPartitionKey(CustomerId); }
       set {; }
   }

   public static string GetPartitionKey(Guid id)
   {
       return id.ToString().Substring(0, 2);
   }
}
```

Before sharing my repository class, I'd like to share a few details about the situations I'm struggling here. I have a partitioned collection (with the PartitionKey property of my Customer class) and I have two requirements for Find operations:

- To be able to find by CustomerId and Channel (same CustomerId can exist for different Channel)
- To be able to check if user exists. The customer exists if the CustomerId or Email exist for the same Channel (again, same CustomerId or Email can exist for different Channel)

My question is about the appropriate indexes, in order to take advantage of them when I find by another thing than the partition key. Let's move to the repository class, then to the indexes:

```
public class MyRepository
{
    private IMongoCollection<Customer> Collection;

public MyRepository()
{
    MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(new MongoUrl("The connection string"));
    settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings() { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 };
            
    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
    var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("db-customer");
    
    this.Collection = database.GetCollection<Customer>("col-customer");
    
    //  What indexes here ?!?
}

public Customer GetByKey(Guid customerId, int channel)
{
    var channelFilter = Builders<Customer>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Channel, customer.Channel);

    var idFilter = Builders<Customer>.Filter.Eq(x => x.CustomerId, customer.CustomerId);
    
    var filter = channelFilter & idFilter;
    
    Customer result = this.Collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
    
    return result;
}

public bool Exists(Customer customer)
{
    var channelFilter = Builders<Customer>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Channel, customer.Channel);
    var emailFilter = Builders<Customer>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Email, customer.Email);

    var idFilter = Builders<Customer>.Filter.Eq(x => x.CustomerId, customer.CustomerId);

    var filter = channelFilter & (emailFilter | idFilter);

    bool found =  this.Collection.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault() != null;

    return found;
}
}
```

So, my question is, which is the best indexing setup for this repository? Should I create one index for each field I'm searching, like this:

```
this.Collection.Indexes.CreateOne(new CreateIndexModel<Customer>(Builders<Customer>.IndexKeys.Ascending(i => i.CustomerId)));
    this.Collection.Indexes.CreateOne(new CreateIndexModel<Customer>(Builders<Customer>.IndexKeys.Ascending(i => i.Channel)));
    this.Collection.Indexes.CreateOne(new CreateIndexModel<Customer>(Builders<Customer>.IndexKeys.Ascending(i => i.Email)));
```

Or should I create compound indexes, depending on the searches I'm trying to attempt, like this?

```
this.Collection.Indexes.CreateOne(new CreateIndexModel<Customer>(Builders<Customer>.IndexKeys.Ascending(i => i.CustomerId).Ascending(i => i.Channel)));
    this.Collection.Indexes.CreateOne(new CreateIndexModel<Customer>(Builders<Customer>.IndexKeys.Ascending(i => i.CustomerId).Ascending(i => i.Email).Ascending(i => i.Channel)));
```

By using Azure monitor checking metrics I always get low RU consumption and overall low response times, but my repository has a few records at this stage. I'm afraid as the number of records scale (this will have millions of records) that the RU consumption becomes too large or the response times too high, or in a worst case scenario, both.

Can I have your two cents on this subject?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You should create a compound index only if your query needs to sort efficiently on multiple fields at once. For queries with multiple filters that don't need to sort, create multiple single field indexes instead of a single compound index. One query uses multiple single field indexes where available.

So, in your case, I see you have multiple filters that don't need to sort. Hence create multiple single field indexes.

Refer [Manage indexing in Azure Cosmos DB's API for MongoDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing) for details